# This is confusing to me

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Up front I am really nasty
>
> In the end I can be tasty
>
> In the middle I serve the Lord
>
> I am a riddle, that's kind of odd

What am I?

Comment: It's confusing for me too.

Comment: I've some ideas but they are somewhere between explicit and blasphemous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only word that I can find that can fit this is

> Conundrum

Up front I am really nasty

> Cons can be quite nasty. Con men will steal your stuff, rob you blind, and you wouldn't even know about it. Or CO which is Carbon Monoxide

In the end I can be tasty

> drums such as drumsticks are indeed quite tasty. Also, you can use rum here as well.

In the middle I serve the Lord

> A nun

I am a riddle, that's kind of odd

> Conundrum: A riddle in which a fanciful question is answered by a pun.

This is confusing to me

> Conundrum: A paradoxical, insoluble, or difficult problem; a dilemma

Comment: everything except the up front clue. Although I like your argument on Con

Comment: @DEEM Darn it, I really thought this was the answer. It worked so well with the title and the last line. So, all but the first clue is correct?

Comment: Your answer is correct but Con is not the word I intended

Comment: @DEEM, okay thanks! I think I can figure it out.

Comment: what about this? rot13(Pneoba zbabkvqr cbvfbavat) don't read if you want to solve it yourself ;-)

Comment: @OfFPiR, nice, I hadn't thought of that!